# How to reference a static class to call a method on it?

Tags: c#, php, self

Is there any equivalent keyword in C# to reference the class from within itself on *static* method calls, without using the proper class name?

The PHP equivalent would be `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it happens inside the class, you don't need to use reference. Just using the method/property name will work, since it is in the current scope. If it is in another class, then it's not SELF, so you need to use the classname.